# How do I use this custom logger in my ini file loaded with fileConfig?

Tags: python, python-logging, rich

I configure logging with ini files and I want to continue to do this, but now I want to use a custom logger.

I can't find examples of using rich console's custom logger with `fileConfig`: https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html

This is my current configuration:

Centralize logging config in this module:

```
# loggingconfig.py
import os
from os import path
import pathlib
import logging
import logging.config

from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger

# Get logging settings via env vars
LOG_CONFIG_PROFILE = os.environ.get("LOG_CONFIG_PROFILE", "humanreadable")
LOGLEVEL = os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "INFO").upper()
LOGLEVEL_NUMBER = logging.getLevelName(LOGLEVEL)
# The numeric value of the DEBUG log level
LOGLEVEL_DEBUG_NUMBER = 10


# Custom formatter for adding/remapping default log fields
class CustomJsonFormatter(jsonlogger.JsonFormatter):
    def add_fields(self, log_record, record, message_dict):
        super().add_fields(log_record, record, message_dict)
        log_record["myfield"] = log_record["levelname"]


# Load logging config file
logging_config_file_path = path.join(
    path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)), f"logging_conf_{LOG_CONFIG_PROFILE}.ini"
)
if not pathlib.Path(logging_config_file_path).is_file():
    raise ValueError(
        f"Could not locate logging config file at: {logging_config_file_path}"
    )

logging.config.fileConfig(logging_config_file_path)


# This logger needs manual config here
logging.getLogger("some.bad.logger").setLevel(logging.WARN)


def get_logger(logger_name):
    """Return instance of the current module's logger."""
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(LOGLEVEL)
    return logger
```

This is the ini file for log config:

```
# logging_conf_humanreadable.ini
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler_simpleFormatter
# Does not work
# class=rich.logging.RichHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler_simpleFormatter
# Does not work
# class=rich.logging.RichHandler

[handler_consoleHandler_simpleFormatter]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)s - %(levelname)s:%(message)s
```

I want to keep CustomJsonFormatter and all the other settings as is, I just want to swap `consoleHandler_simpleFormatter` for rich.

When I try to use the fully qualified class I get: `KeyError: 'handler_RichHandler'`